# How to find all roots of system equations

Tags: python, numerical-methods, scipy-optimize, nonlinear-optimization

I have these "simple" equations (it's a chemical system for finding equilibrium concentrations, but it doesn't matter):

```
X * (1 + K_AC * C + K_AB * Y) = A_0
Y * (1 + K_BC * C + K_AB * X) = Z
C * (1 + K_AC * X + K_BC * Y) = C_0
```

where `K_AB`, `K_AC`, `K_BC` are known positive parameters (not random numbers, but with complex dependencies among themselves)

I also know `A_0`, `C_0`, `C` (they are positive and `C < C_0`), and want to solve this system to find `X`, `Y`, `Z`. But this system has many solutions, and I need to find them all (in real numbers), but I know it's impossible to find all roots in a general situation, so I need to set search areas (because I'm interested in specific solutions, that definitely exist - I'm interested in a solution with positive `X`, `Y`, `Z`, but this existence of this solution depends on the initial `A_0`, `C_0`, `C`, so I'm interested in solution/solutions with positive `X` and real `Y`, `Z`). And I really don't know how many solutions this system has, but I think the number of solutions is less than 100.

I don't know how to find all solutions to a system with multiple variables and I don't really know if there is an algorithm for my system to find all the roots. I tried to find convenient for my task function in the module `scipy.optimize`, but I found `scipy.optimize.root` and other similar functions and these methods don't work for me, because they can only find one solution. I also tried using `scipy.optimize.fsolve`, but I get only one root too. Is there a method or function that will help me to find all solutions and also it's great if this method will work fast enough (I need to solve this system very often with different parameters)? Or maybe Is there a way to set search bounds (a.k.a. `scipy.optimize.Bounds`) but for fast enough methods like newton, hybr, etc., not like basinhoppin or binsearch?

Comment: Usually equations are written with one side equal to 0, so you should move the terms that you have in the right to the left part of the equation. Then it's unclear what are coefficients here, can you write the equations using X, Y and Z as the unknows, so we know what are unknowns and what are coefficients? then, if you have some restrictions, such as `C>0` `C_0>0` and `C_0 > C` you should write this also as extra equations, not as part of your explanations. And what you mean by "complex dependencies among themselves"? Are `K_AB, K_AC, K_BC` complex numbers or real numbers?

Comment: 1. I edited my question, so now It's clear what are unknowns.
2. K_AB, K_AC, K_BC are real, but I don't know the relationships. This is an example: K_AB = 790823546760.1965, K_AC = 394050.18502614903, K_BC = 534597412.9831481

Comment: And I think it's important to know that 1e-08 < A_0 < 1e-04 and C < C_0 = 1e-10 (This is also known coefficients: A_0, C, C_0)

Comment: 3 quadratic equations with full coefficient set will have generically 8 solutions, possibly all of them complex. As the unknowns are X,Y,Z and the second equation is coupled only in one direction, the reduced system is 2 quadratic equations in 2 variables, reducing the number of possible solutions to 4. The last equation is linear, reducing the whole task to finding the 2 roots of one quadratic equation.

Comment: I think you should write your equations in Polynomial form, since this is how you then introduce the coefficients to solvers, and also the equations should be equal to 0 in one of the sides. Then any additional restrictions should be put together with the equations. Now you have some restrictions written in the text of the questions, other restrictions in comments. The first equation is then `(1 + K_AC * C) * X + K_AB * X*Y - A_0  = 0` where you have an X, XY and independent terms. Can you write the equations like this So we can see what terms and coefficients you have?

Answer (score 0):

Three equations three unknowns; this is an exactly-determined problem i.e. only one solution. Root finding in scipy chokes on this problem, but generic minimisation does fine. There are methods to set bounds, but you've totally omitted what those would be so I assume they don't matter:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy
from numpy.random import default_rng


def get_error(A: float, B: float, B_0: float) -> tuple[float, ...]:
    return (
        A*(1 + K_AC*C + K_AB*B) - A_0,
        B*(1 + K_BC*C + K_AB*A) - B_0,
        C*(1 + K_AC*A + K_BC*B) - C_0,
    )


def get_scalar_error(x: np.ndarray) -> float:
    error = get_error(*x)
    return np.dot(error, error)


rand = default_rng()
K_AB, K_AC, K_BC, A_0, C = rand.random(size=5)
C_0 = C + rand.random()
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(
    fun=get_scalar_error,
    x0=(1, 1, 1),
)
A, B, B_0 = result.x
print('ABC:', A, B, C)
print('ABC0:', A_0, B_0, C_0)
print('Error:', get_error(*result.x))
```

```
ABC: 2.7154742458255403 -1.7413862978391461 0.9629958541866175
ABC0: 0.8737725414657669 -4.777551070025461 1.9026661578957855
Error: (-1.5073946657562232e-07, -2.565059640247114e-07, 2.0278476986490546e-07)
```

Comment: 1. If we have 3 line-independent linear equations and 3 unknowns, therefore the system has only 1 solution, but my system is non-linear, so your solution dnot suitable for me.

2. I need reasonably "good" numerical method, such as Newton's methods and others (It's easy to calculate a Jacobian for my system, and usually methods that use a Jacobian are better than methods without it). I know how to set bounds for brentq, basinhoppin and etc, but I want to set bounds for much better methods.

Comment: @Artem you realize that minimize accepts both bounds and a Jacobian, right?